# Grep the substring within the last occurrence of single quotes

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to grep a substring within a string inside the last occurance of single quotes.below is my String :

```
'abc''cde''efg'
```

Below is the command which I have used;

```
echo "'abc''cde''efg'" |rev|grep -m1 -oP "(?<=') .*?(?=')"
```

But I am not getting desired output. I am getting fge while it should  `efg`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Code Snippet :

```
sed -r "s/.*'(\w+)'$/\1/g"
efg

grep -oP ".*'\K[^']+(?=')"
efg
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the whole string, you should also reverse the result after extraction.

However, using a PCRE regex (enabled via the `P` option) for you case can simplify the task:

```
grep -oP ".*'\K[^']+"
```

Here, `.*'` matches up to the last (rightmost) occurrence of `'`, [`\K` match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) will discard the whole matched text and `[^']+` will put into the result 1 or more chars other than `'`.

Since not all systems offer the PCRE functionality with `grep`, you might consider an `awk` solution, too:

```
awk -F\'\' 'gsub(/^'"'"'+|'"'"'+$/, "", $0) {print $NF}'
```

Here, the string is split into fields with a `''` substring (`-F\'\'`), then the leading/trailing `'` are removed (`gsub(/^'"'"'+|'"'"'+$/, "", $0)`) and then the last field is printed (`print $NF`).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Srftsu).